# How does light not have mass?

Tags: special-relativity, visible-light, photons, mass

How is it possible for light to have zero mass because it was my understanding that in order for "stuff" to exist it has to have some form of mass? And if it does not have mass then can it be affected by gravity.

Comment: "...because it was my understanding that..." Where did you acquire this understanding?

Comment: Your understanding was incorrect, because you were previously taught a simplified version of reality. Now you’re learning that mass isn’t necessary for existence. Physicists think that in the very early universe *no* particles had mass! Now most do but some — photons, gluons, and gravitons — don’t.

Comment: @chocolate king This is a great question and the answers so far do not come close to answering it. In fact they're about as ridicules as some explaining why or why not there is a God. There have been hundreds of scientist through out the centuries asking questions that the status quo laughed at. There was a time that no one believed in atoms, let alone protons, neutrons and electrons. Every answer ever given as to why photons don't have mass makes no since, is incomplete or some kind of fudge. Everyone keeps using words like matter, energy, stuff,  or things. Anything real should have a mass.

Comment: Voting to reopen. The questioner is asking a simple question, not proposing their own personal theory. They have a misunderstanding, but we do not close questions just because the questioner has a misunderstanding.

Comment: Just for the record, this is not "a great question." It is a bad question and it is a compound question. The question of "how" light does not have mass is unanswerable. We can't tell you "how," we can only tell you that it does not have mass. The second part of this compound question, i.e., the part reading *"if it does not have mass then can it be affected by gravity. [sic]"* seems to show a complete lack of any independent attempt at a research: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_general_relativity#Sources_of_gravity

Comment: True. Science does not provide much in the way of why and how, rather, science is the application of an epistemic theory (empiricism) that attempts to discover what is, in as far as observation is capable.

Comment: Its a great and simple question that has never been answered. Think about the smallest mass ever measured. Now according to the status quo there can't be a mass smaller than that, just because we don't have the tools to measure it? Reasonable theories can explain how gravity effects real particle with mass, but not massless particles. I mean talk about oxymorons. Besides the question is asking How light does not have mass. Just saying its unanswerable is unacceptable. Just posting a link is just as bad. If you don't understand the question then don't tell everyone else its unanswerable.

Comment: @BillAlsept. Saying such a question is unanswerable is certainly acceptable within the framework of science. Hume and Kant have dealt coup de grace to metaphysics as a scientific pursuit; such concerns as yours belong to the realm of philosophy. There is probably a stack exchange for that too. I don't believe that scientists are epistemically limited, however, science is.

Comment: @Albertus Magnus that approach to physics, reminds me of what Lord Kelvin reportedly said in 1900 that physics was complete, just before groundbreaking discoveries reshaped the field.

Comment: @Bill Aslept. No. My statement does not allude in any way to the completeness of physics. In fact, because physics is limited to strictly empirical knowledge, it is as a mode of human knowing, terribly incomplete. It is true, however, that physicists must keep an open mind, and that relativity was largely theoretical and accused of being non-scientific by contemporary critics; a situation that changed with subsequent experimental verification. However, in principle, at least; a theory must be testable in order for it to be a scientific theory.

Comment: @Albertus Magnus Yes a theory must be testable as well as questioned which is more to the OP's points. Physics is the study of Matter, Energy, Space and Time. Unlike philosophical and mathematical virtuals, physics theories are different because they focus on explaining and predicting real and physical phenomena. Your edging closer to philosophical or virtual when you start talking momentum without mass. Like I said there is no better oxymoron than massless particle. How can you test something that makes no since?  Momentum without mass can't be explained in real terms without fudging.

Comment: @BIll Aslept. Well, my fellow in sophistry, the only thing left is to wait to see who racks up the votes. Unfoutunately, for us, I doubt any one will care! I now take my leave of the Agora.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, most natural scientists recognize that there are two kinds of "stuff" in the universe. Matter and also, energy. Although modern physics asserts that matter and energy are equivalent in the sense that they are interchangeable, i.e. $E=mc^2$, energy is not required to posses mass. Energy can stem purely from field momentum. In fact the famous mass-energy relation alluded to earlier is but a special case of the full relativistic energy-momentum-mass relationship given by:$$E^2=p^2c^2+m^2c^4.$$ The relation $E=mc^2$ comes from the extreme case when energy is totally comprised of the massive type, where $p=0$, similarly, light represents an extreme when the energy is present without any massive contribution, i.e. $m=0$ gives the result that: $E^2=p^2c^2$. This is the kind of energy that light has; and is the source of energy that powers the photoelectric effect employed in many modern technologies.
As for light's interaction with gravity, despite its lack of mass, one must account for a fuller understanding of gravitation that goes beyond Newton's concept of universal gravity. Particularly, gravity is now identified with the intrinsic geometry of the space-time continuum, rather than a long range action at a distance type of force like the electromagnetic field. Light is bent by gravity because it is travelling, unaccelerated, through a curved space-time along a path of minimal distance known as a "geodesic".
All of the above phenomena are the result of improved knowledge of physics that has come about as a 20th century revolution in physics largely initiated by Albert Einstein. You may well enjoy adding some introductory reading on Einstein's special and general theory of relativity to fill the gaps in your traditional understanding of matter and energy and space-time.

Comment: It's not because I'm jealous of the two upvotes or anything like that but it is impossible to do a minimal amount of justice to Newton AND/OR Einstein without the context of Einstein's thoughts on his theory. There is a paper by A. Einstein, it explains what General  Relativity means.

Comment: I agree. The genius of Newton and Einstein is astounding. Primary sources for both of these should be on every great book shelf.

Comment: Einstein is the man. Though.

Answer (score 1):

At its core, things fall because of time dilation.  Nobel Laureate Kip Thorne referred to what he calls “Einstein’s Law of Time Warps”.   He said, “Things like to live where they age the most slowly.  Gravity pulls them there.   And so as an application, the Earth's mass warps time according to Einstein. It slows time near the surface of the Earth. And this time warp is what produces gravity.”

This dilation of time near a planet, star or galaxy is also responsible for the bending of light, but for a slightly different reason. And this shows you why light does not need mass in order to be affected by gravity.  You have seen the refraction of light when it enters a prism at an angle.  The explanation given was always because the glass prism is a denser material.  But what this really means is that light travels at a slower speed inside the glass then it does in the air.  So when light hits the glass at an angle, it bends towards the slower speed.   The same thing happens when light approaches a planet at an angle.  It hits the dilated time near the planet and bends towards the planet. It's just refraction.

This does not in any way disagree with the other answers given to your question, it just provides a concrete, non-mathy explanation for how relativity explains the bending of light.

Comment: Time dilation is only one part of spacetime curvature. If you don't also take spatial curvature into account you'll get the wrong value for e.g. the deflection of light by the sun. The picture of time dilation "causing" gravity is pop-sci and incomplete. The real story is given by the Einstein field equations.

Comment: Your answer does not explain "how light does not have mass". Besides that, if "Things like to live where they age the most slowly, then why do they need gravity to pull them there. Nor do you explain how gravity pulls them there, or how gravity warps space time?? Specifically the OP wants to know "How light does not have mass", if that's what it takes to interact with gravity.

Comment: @BillAlsept perhaps I was not explicit by saying that light does not need mass in order to be affected by the time dilation of gravity. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @EricSmith I've always found it wise not to argue with Nobel prize winners. When you can explain how the Einstein field equations work in a real, physical sense, then the rest of the world can understand them. I prefer to deal in physical things rather than mathematical abstracts.

Comment: Now I understand the context of the downvote. Nonsense like this. I have time to prove it but its not worth it, proving to any of my 6 walls is more proficient. Free fall in what is known as Schwartzwald solution, for instance, is the reason. There is no pull of the earth in this mathematical formulation of gravity. It stems from the field equation in empty space, around spherically symmetric, static object which likely has a mass. It is light that obeys least time. Time dilation is symmetric is SR but not in gravity.

Comment: @foolishmuse : I find that particular Nobel prize winner's textbook (Misner, Thorne, and Wheeler's "Gravitation") far more accurate and complete than his oversimplified pop-sci descriptions.

Answer (score -1):

Two questions come to mind:

1. What is mass?
2. What is energy?

The second question is difficult, but let us lose all of generality and speak of energy Conservation instead. In classical physics (Analytical is always better), it is a scalar quantity conserved with respect to the passage of Time. Hamiltonian formulation of mechanics, where the Hamiltonian function is the Hero, is a sophisticated way to formulate total energy of a system, where total mean Kinetic (Energy of motion, which is $0$ in a physically static system) and Potential (Literally potentially kinetic, but is not kinetic) Energies, added together.

The mother of all four-vectors (Meaning the principle of Special Relativity (SR) has a chance to realize itself as a mathematical procedure, and its output is not affected by applying transformations called Lorentz Transformations) is infinitesimal space-time displacement. It has two realizations, like any four vector. In SR it is most favorable to start with a covariant vector, which has the index not in the top, but at the bottom. It does not carry the signature of the metric tensor. Applying the Minkowski metric tensor (It is its own inverse as a matrix) negates the time component and raises the index, and outputs a contravariant vector:

$$X^\mu := \eta^{\mu\nu } X_\nu=\eta^{\mu 0 } cdt + \eta^{\mu 1 } dx + \eta^{\mu 2 } dy + \eta^{\mu 3 } dz=-\delta^{\mu 0} cdt + \delta^{\mu 1} dx + \delta^{\mu 2} dy + \delta^{\mu 3} dz$$

$$d \tau ^2= X_\mu X^\mu=-c^2dt^2+dx^2+dy^2+dz^2$$

$$P_\mu := mV_\mu := m\frac {dX_{\mu }}{d\tau}$$

The last is the Four-Momentum. The $0$ component is Relativistic Energy, No longer conserved in different speed of motion, but Squaring it and subtracting the square of magnitude of spatial momentum is indeed conserved. We might as well then remain seated in our Rest Frame and calculate this invariant with ease. No motion means no spatial momentum, and the Relativistic Energy is as such, but we multiply by $c^2$ to have dimensions of energy:

$$E_0^2:= -c^2 \eta_{\mu\nu } P^\nu P^\mu =-c^2 P_0 P^0 = m^2 c^4 \frac{dt^2}{d\tau^2}=m^2 c^4$$

$$E_0=mc^2$$

A static frame, meaning this is no other than potential energy, for the sake of existence, a mass exists.

Promoting the procedure to a relativistic picture of non relativistic motion we get:

$$E=mc^2 \sqrt{1+ \frac{P^2}{m^2 c^2}}=mc^2+\frac{P^2}{2m}$$

The quadratic term in the Quadratic McLaurin expansion is Newton's kinetic energy. This is a double whammy, because we already knew $mc^2$ is supposed to be potential energy.

This brings us to question $1$, which we had now answered somehow by asking about the nature of energy.!

About your train of though:

I believe it is appropriate to replace "Stuff" with ***Causality***.

Light is the upper bound, and turn out to be the maximal (Also an upper bound but is included rather than left with a chance to be excluded from the set of speeds) speed that allows two events to be in cause-effect relation with each other.

The bizzare fact is that a massive mediator ($m>0$) cannot reach this maximum, and light, being massless, can never ***leave*** this maximum.

In General Relativity, photons do have a VIP seat:

In terms of being Electro Magnetic field, then in case of a central charge the empty space time around it obeys the field equation: "Ricci Tensor = Constant * Stress-Energy Tensor". The scalar vanishes because the field strength tensor is anti symmetric.

$$R_{\mu\nu}=CT_{\mu\nu}$$

It means that photons pave the curvature and also portray it. They curve by twice the amount of massive objects.